# Bad Link on Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

1. Go here: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/18165/net-ninja-a-k-a-brilliant-engineer-who-can-get-match-com?a=lsE6AVi
2. Scroll down to the How to Apply section.

The issue is self-evident.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgBAe.jpg]

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the report Tommy, we fixed this.